# Node Express Js

Tags: node.js, express

I am working on Node Js and I am facing issue in my routes.js file and app.js file.
Routes file is no working.

App.js code

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const routes = express.Router('./routes/routes');
const path = require('path');
const methodOverride = require('method-override');
const moment= require('moment');
app.locals.moment=moment;
app.locals.shortDateFormat="MM/DD/YYYY";

app.set('view engine', 'pug');
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'index.jade'));
```

Route.js code

```
var express=require('express');
var routes= express.Router();
var controllers= require('../controllers');

// homepage routes
routes.get('/',controllers.homeController.index);
```

Comment: I think you should consult the documentation ~ https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html#express-router. TL;DR [`express.Router()`](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#express.router) does not accept a file path parameter

Comment: Thank you Phill. For sure I will consult the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

You need to export the routes from `Route.js` file

```
var express=require('express');
var routes= express.Router();
var controllers= require('../controllers');

// homepage routes
routes.get('/',controllers.homeController.index);

module.exports = routes
```

and in `app.js`

```
app.use('/', routes)
```